# Ionic not returning sql data from factory to the controller

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

So, I have created a factory to query the db and return data. Inside the method, I can print to the console. But when I check the return data from inside a controller, it's empty, please look at the code below and see if you can help.

Here is the factory

```
   rs.factory("userService",function($http,$ionicLoading,$cordovaProgress,$cordovaSQLite,$q){
    var user = {};

 /**get user  data */
       user.getData = function(){
      //stores from the local database
       var userData = [];
       var query = "SELECT * FROM users";
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function(res) {

     for (var i=0; i < res.rows.length; i++){
       userData.push(res.rows.item(i));
     }
      console.log("User Data : " + JSON.stringify(userData));//this works

    }, function (err) {
      console.error(err);
    })

     return userData;

};
 return user;

});
```

The controller:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $http, $state, $cordovaSQLite,$ionicNavBarDelegate,userService) {

 console.log(userService.getData()); // is empty
})
```

Nothing is returned here.

Comment: I have a question related. The short anwser: all the database operation are asynchronous check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39563879/sqlite-plugin-for-cordova-code-running-backwards

Answer (score 0):

1st thing you need to return a `userData` from success callback of your promise, & thereafter return `$cordovaSQLLite.execute` promise, so that you can chain that promise inside controller

```
user.getData = function() {
  //stores from the local database
  var userData = [];
  var query = "SELECT * FROM users";
  //returning promise
  return $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function(res) {
    for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
      userData.push(res.rows.item(i));
    }        
    //return data once user Data created
    return userData;
  }, function(err) {
    console.error(err);
  })
};
```

Then inside controller you could access data by having .then function over that method

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $http, $state,  $cordovaSQLite,$ionicNavBarDelegate,userService) {
   userService.getData().then(function(userData){
      console.log(userData);
   });
})
```